# How can I access my Windows file system files under the WSL Ubuntu app?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have found only one resource on this specific case, and it doesn't work. It says to find part of the Windows file system under `/mnt/<user-name>`, yet my `/mnt` directory has no `brady` (my user) at all. Do I have to mount the FS myself, and how do I do so, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll find the C: drive mounted at `/mnt/c` so your Windows user account files should be at `/mnt/c/Users/<user-name>`.

Conversely, you can see your WSL user's file system in Windows Explorer at `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\<user-name>` (if you chose Ubuntu 18.04)

From the WSL shell you can type `explorer.exe .` to open the current directory in the WSL filesystem in Windows Explorer.

Note that your WSL username is not the same as your Windows username unless you set them up to be identical. Also, the WSL filesystem is usually case-sensitive, unlike Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer. Case-sensitive is not a problem, even though Windows and PowerShell aren't case-sensitive, I am a case-sensitive user.